How can I install Minecraft Education on Linux Mint 22 (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)
I would like to install Minecraft Education Edition on Linux Mint 22. I have tried using wine and I can get through the installation process but I can't get it to launch. I then tried installing some other things through wine first and I ran "wine Minecraft.Windows.exe" in the terminal and managed to get it to launch but then I get
the error shown in this picture and it is also an older version.
I also get the following error
0238:err:ole:create_server class {9052024a-9cde-4aa8-b35f-737bfee80584} not registered
0238:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {9052024a-9cde-4aa8-b35f-737bfee80584} could be created for context 0x4

Thank you to whoever helps me with this :)

You're wasting your time.
